# Problema de instalación Mondodb

Tags: mongodb

He querido instalar mongodb pero me aparece un mensaje de error en la instalación. No sé a qué se deba. Dice así:

> Setup wizard ended prematurely because of an error. your system has
>   not been modified. To install this program at a later time, run setup
>   wizard again. Click the finish button to exit the setup wizard.

Comment: Prueba a quitar el check a la opción install MongoDB Compass, antes de instalar. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Seguramente será por que no habras creado la siguiente ruta en tu disco;

`C:\data

C:\data\db`

Esta ruta de directorios es necesaria antes de hacer la instalacion de mongodb.

Te adjunto [aqui](https://gist.github.com/AlejoJamC/b8635af765ac7495c4931403b97a0d78) un tutorial de todos los pasos para instalar mongo correctamente.